# Telerik RadComboBox OnClientItemsRequesting $find(RadCombobox1) returns null

Tags: c#, javascript, telerik

I am using radcombobox which calls a web service for its data which works fine here is my code

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="Country" runat="server"   EnableLoadOnDemand="true"
     Skin="Forest"  >
     <WebServiceSettings Path="DropDownWebService.asmx" Method="GetCountry" />     
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

it will return all the countries from my db.
after this I have another combo for city and its code is

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="City" runat="server" OnClientItemsRequesting = "OnClientItemsRequesting"    EnableLoadOnDemand="true"
     Skin="Forest"  >
     <WebServiceSettings Path="DropDownWebService.asmx" Method="GetCity" />     
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

And my javascript code is

```
 function OnClientItemsRequesting(sender, eventArgs) {
        alert(document.getElementById('<%# Country.ClientID %>'));
             var combo = $find("<%# Country.ClientID %>");
             alert(combo);   


        }
```

I want to get the value of country rad combo so that I can filter it for city but in alert it only return null even I have place this javascript code block in  RadScriptBlock  but still it does not work.

can any one help me on this!!! I will be very thankful to all.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the RadComboBox is not placed within a template control. If it is placed with template control, you need find with template control. If it is not placed within template control, try $get("<%= Country.ClientID %>").

Comment: $get("<%# Country.ClientID %>"); didnt help I have not placed it inside template control but I did try to place it inside telerik:RadAjaxPanel still it didnt work for me.

Comment: Try use RadScriptBlock in this page, it will overcome "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)." ERROR

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong:  [find Radcombobox](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-basics.html)
    **Replace:**

```
 var combo = $find("<%# Country.ClientID %>");
```

**TO:**

```
var combo = $find("<%= Country.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: If I replace # with = this is what I get on page "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)." ERROR

Comment: sender will give me the object of city combo which I dont want I want the object of country combobox

Comment: I had tried  var context = eventArgs.get_context(); that gives me the object of city combo not country

Comment: @user1933955 you want the obj of country control .what are u saying in 2nd comment